# How to get the time at which a transaction was added to the pool?

Tags: monerod, daemon, monerod-commands

Can we get information about when a transaction was added to the pool and also when it was mined into a block?

Is there a demon RPC to get that. Or is it generally stored in the block header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_transaction_pool` daemon RPC returns the current state of the txpool. The `transactions` field in the reply is an array of data for each transaction currently in the pool, and includes a `id_hash` field (the txid) and a `receive_time` field (the time it was received). Reminder that since the txpool is a local thing, different clients will receive transactions at different times.

The time a transaction was mined into a block is that block's timestamp. Daemon RPCs like `get_block_header_by_height` and others give you data which includes a `timestamp` field, which is that time. Note that this timestamp is miner controlled, and thus can deviate about two hours from the real time.

Both of these times are UNIX timestamps, which means they're seconds since the epoch (1970/01/01).

Comment: can we get data for historic transaction .. Like a transaction that has already been mined into the block.. I need the time when that was added to the pool!

Comment: This data is not kept. Again, every node will lkikely add the tx in its txpool at a different time. If you're interested in keeping this data for stats, you can run with --log-level 0,txpool:INFO, which will print whenever a tx is added to the txpool, including the timestamp.